# Why EventListener doesnt work after remove and re-add an element

Tags: javascript

I have p element where an EventListener is attached to it but after remove this element and re-add it back to the DOM the listener no longer works

Here's the code

```js
var parent = document.querySelector('.parent');

create(1);

document.querySelector('p').addEventListener('click',  function(){
  alert('ok');
}, false);

document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click',  function(){
  refreshDom();
}, false);


function create(n) {
 var div = document.createElement('div');
  var p = document.createElement('p');
  var btn = document.createElement('button');
  
  p.innerHTML = 'Dom Created ' + n;
 btn.textContent = 'click';
  
  
  div.appendChild(p);
  div.appendChild(btn);
  parent.appendChild(div);
}

function refreshDom() {
clearDom();
create(2);
}

function clearDom() {
var div = document.querySelector('div > div');
parent.removeChild(div);
}
```

```html
<html>
  <body>
    <div class="parent"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

I expect the alert popup every time i click on the p element but it only popup once before i click on the button

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not removing and re-adding the same `<p>` element, you're removing the one with a listener attached and adding an entirely new element. The same goes for your `<button>`. If you want the new element to respond to clicks, you need to give it its own listener:

```
function create (n) {
  var div = document.createElement('div');
  var p = document.createElement('p');
  var btn = document.createElement('button');

  p.innerHTML = 'Dom Created ' + n;
  p.addEventListener('click', function() {
    alert('ok');
  }, false);

  btn.textContent = 'click';
  btn.addEventListener('click', refreshDom, false);

  div.appendChild(p);
  div.appendChild(btn);
  parent.appendChild(div);
}
```

Or give the parent `<div>` a listener that only pays attention to `<p>`s and another for `<button>`s:

```js
var parent = document.querySelector('.parent');

create(1);

parent.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
  if (!event.target.closest('p')) return;
  alert('ok');
}, false);

parent.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
  if (!event.target.closest('button')) return;
  refreshDom();
}, false);

function create(n) {
  var div = document.createElement('div');
  var p = document.createElement('p');
  var btn = document.createElement('button');
  
  p.innerHTML = 'Dom Created ' + n;
  btn.textContent = 'click';

  div.appendChild(p);
  div.appendChild(btn);
  parent.appendChild(div);
}

function refreshDom() {
  clearDom();
  create(2);
}

function clearDom() {
  var div = document.querySelector('div > div');
  parent.removeChild(div);
}
```

```html
<html>

<body>
  <div class="parent"></div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Excellent answer! But I hope you don't mind a question: I don't fully understand how `event.target.matches('p')` works. Is this the reason?: when a `<p>` is clicked, the click event bubbles up to the parentElement, that has the event handler attached to it by `addEventListener`, so it runs the attached handler function. But the parentElement would be event.currentTarget, while event.target is always the first element that triggered the event (so a `<p>` element if I clicked on it). Am I correct?

Comment: @flen Yes. But I was wrong. `event.target.matches('p')` won't be true for elements _inside_ `<p>`s. `event.target.closest('p')` is only truthy if the target _is_ or _is inside of_ a `<p>`, and is a better test.

Answer (score 2):

why not working: listenner only added once and binded to the p tag created by `create(1)`

quik fix : move addlistener into create

```js
var parent = document.querySelector('.parent');

create(1);

function create(n) {
  var div = document.createElement('div');
  var p = document.createElement('p');
  var btn = document.createElement('button');

  p.innerHTML = 'Dom Created ' + n;
  btn.textContent = 'click';


  div.appendChild(p);
  div.appendChild(btn);
  parent.appendChild(div);


  document.querySelector('p').addEventListener('click', function() {
    alert('ok');
  }, false);

  document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click', function() {
    refreshDom();
  }, false);

}

function refreshDom() {
  clearDom();
  create(2);
}

function clearDom() {
  var div = document.querySelector('div > div');
  parent.removeChild(div);
}
```

```html
<html>

<body>
  <div class="parent"></div>
</body>

</html>
```

better fix : use delegate ( http://api.jquery.com/on/ )

```js
var parent = document.querySelector('.parent');

$('.parent').on('click', 'p', function() {
  alert('ok');
})
$('.parent').on('click', 'button', function() {
  refreshDom();
})


create(1);

function create(n) {
  var div = document.createElement('div');
  var p = document.createElement('p');
  var btn = document.createElement('button');

  p.innerHTML = 'Dom Created ' + n;
  btn.textContent = 'click';


  div.appendChild(p);
  div.appendChild(btn);
  parent.appendChild(div);


}

function refreshDom() {
  clearDom();
  create(2);
}

function clearDom() {
  var div = document.querySelector('div > div');
  parent.removeChild(div);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>

<body>
  <div class="parent"></div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: `delegated event handler` solution is really good.

Answer (score 0):

You just add event listener `click` to element `p` once, but the element `p` will be removed and recreate new one after you do click. So you need to rebind event listener to element `p` one more time.